# How to use mongo aggregate sample with spring data mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to use mongoDB 3.2 feature `$sample` in aggregation to get some random collection

how to use it with spring data mongo api ?

Answer (score 0):

In current spring data version `$sample`is not a supported operation. You can see full list of supported aggregation operations [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.supported-aggregation-operations)

Comment: @arvin if you will write directly mongodb query, no need to switch java-mongo-driver. You can do that with spring data via `BasicQuery` too. So you wouldn't lose all the good stuff spring data offers.